# WebAssembly: Export namespace from C++ library to JavaScript

Tags: c++, webassembly, emscripten

I'm trying to port the [lhslib](https://github.com/bertcarnell/lhslib) library (written in C++) to WebAssembly using emscripten (emcc v. 1.40.1, clang v. 12.0.0, macOS 10.15.5). Unfortunately I have a very limited understanding of C++, so please bear with me.

So far, I forked the repo, created a `build` folder, and from there started to try and convert the [randomLHS.cpp](https://github.com/bertcarnell/lhslib/blob/master/src/lhslib/randomLHS.cpp) file to WASM:

```cpp
// a short overview of what the file looks like
#include "LHSCommonDefines.h"
#include "utilityLHS.h"

namespace lhslib 
{
    void randomLHS(int n, int k, bclib::matrix<int> & result, bclib::CRandom<double> & oRandom)
    {
    // further contents of the file
    }
}
```

Running

```
emcc ../src/lhslib/randomLHS.cpp -I../src/bclib -o randomLHS.html
```

creates the expected files `randomLHS.wasm` ,`randomLHS.js`, and `randomLHS.html`.
However, when serving the `html` file and inspecting the `Module` object created by emscripten, it does not contain the desired `randomLHS` function.

I then read about the [`EXPORTED_FUNCTIONS`](https://emscripten.org/docs/porting/connecting_cpp_and_javascript/Interacting-with-code.html#interacting-with-code-ccall-cwrap) option and proceeded to try the following

```
emcc ../src/lhslib/randomLHS.cpp -I../src/bclib -o randomLHS.html -s EXPORTED_FUNCTIONS='["_randomLHS"]' -s EXPORTED_RUNTIME_METHODS='["ccall", "cwrap"]'
```

This results in the following error:

```
emcc: error: undefined exported function: "_randomLHS" [-Wundefined] [-Werror]
```

Unfortunately I couldn't find any examples showcasing how to export a namespace (as in the `randomLHS` file), or how to specify a function from the namespace that should be exported.
Could you guide me on how I could achieve this?

Thanks for you help!

Comment: How are you using this exported function? Please add that code also.

Comment: Thanks for your comment! In JavaScript, I would first define the function with `const randomLHS = Module.cwrap('_randomLHS ', 'number', ['number', 'number']);` and then use it like this: `const draws = randomLHS(100,3)`, which would then create a LHS with 100 draws for 3 variables. This is the default way of calling functions exported from C++ using emscripten in JS according to their documentation. Does this answer you question?

Comment: Sure, no problem. Partially. Could you please [edit](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/63288110/edit) your question and add the sample `.html` file where you're calling this after loading the module? Actually, I was looking for a [minimal, reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Comment: Are you able to export and run a test function under a namespace? If not, you should try that first. Or, is it specific to this library?

Comment: Sorry, I’m currently on vacation and don’t have acccess to a computer! Actually the minimum working example would be to clone the lhslib, and then use the build command outlined in the original question, as the command fails (with the given error) before it actually builds a HTML file. I tried an example from the test library before, which worked without errors. Thanks for helping me on this one!

Answer (score 0):

So according to the [emscripten docs](https://emscripten.org/docs/porting/connecting_cpp_and_javascript/Interacting-with-code.html#interacting-with-code-ccall-cwrap) on using `ccall` and `cwrap`:

> These methods can be used with compiled C functions — name-mangled C++ functions won’t work.

I believe there are [other ways](https://emscripten.org/docs/porting/connecting_cpp_and_javascript/Interacting-with-code.html) to do this; check out [WebIDL Binder](https://emscripten.org/docs/porting/connecting_cpp_and_javascript/WebIDL-Binder.html#webidl-binder) and [Embind](https://emscripten.org/docs/porting/connecting_cpp_and_javascript/embind.html#embind).